# List only aliases that do not match ServerName prefixed with "alias www." from apachectl -S

Tags: bash, apache

I am trying to gather a list of aliases that do not match the ServerName directive of my apache configuration files. Here is the syntax I am using to generate the output.

```
apachectl -S | cut -d" " -f12,13,18,19 | sed -e 's/namevhost //;/.conf/d;/^$/d;/^127/d;/is$/d' | uniq
```

Here is my output that is generated by the previous "pipeline" of commands.

```
logwatch-jgpihole.com
  alias www.logwatch-jgpihole.com
jgpihole.com
  alias jgpihole.local
  alias piholeadmin.com
jgrantham.ddns.net
```

The output I am trying to achieve would look like so.

```
logwatch-jgpihole.com
jgpihole.com
  alias jgpihole.local
  alias piholeadmin.com
jgrantham.ddns.net
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try the obvious `grep -v 'alias www\.'`? Though refactoring to an Awk script would get rid of `cut`, `sed`, and `uniq` too.

Comment: Thank you for your speedy response. That worked and now I feel like a dummy for not thinking to use grep -v. Can you please repost your comment as an answer so I can accept it? Also, if it's not too much trouble to give an example of the awk script you suggested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious solution is to pipe your output to

```
grep -v 'alias www\.'
```

A tangled mess of `cut` and `sed` and `grep` is often a sign that you should look at Awk instead.

```
apachectl -S |
awk '{ a = $12 OFS $13 OFS $18 OFS $19
    gsub(/namevhost /, "", a)
    if (a !~ /\.conf|^$|^127|is$|alias www\./ && !b[a]++)
        print a }'
```

This is kind of tangled, too, because I don't know what your `apachectl` output looks like; probably many things could be made significantly easier to understand and update with a bit of context.